# Any way to 'format as code' before paste?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting

When I paste code into the Stack Overflow editor, my process typically takes the following steps:

1. Highlight code.
2. Copy.
3. Paste at desired location.
4. Highlight pasted code.
5. Mark as formatted.

Step 4 here always seems unnecessary, because I am re-highlighting again the same content. It seems that there should be a way to "paste as code". Then the steps could instead be:

1. Highlight code.
2. Copy.
3. Select desired location, and
4. "Mark" for code to be pasted there.
5. Paste.

This would be a faster and simpler process. Marking the location as code with the {} button seems like it should work for this, but it always only formats the first line and I have to go and highlight anyway.

Is there any way to "mark for paste as code" on Stack Overflow?

Comment: open up the stack snippet window and paste the code in there in the appropriate section.

Comment: or you put an extra 4 spaces or a tab at the start of all your lines of code before you paste. this is why sometimes when when you see new users post their function the consider in the function body is fine. i think most IDE you can select text, press tab which adds the tab space then copy and paste. your first list only becomes 3